# Detecting the hydrothermal alteration zones?

Tags: geology, mineralogy, remote-sensing

Is it possible to use remote sensing to determine Hydrothermal alteration zones without resorting to collecting samples from the Area of study?

Comment: Which hydrothermal alteration zones are you referring to? My guess it that you're talking about things around porphyry intrusions, gossans, etc, but you have to be clear.

Comment: I mean the hydrothermal alteration zones associated with gold mineralization